# Странное поведение splice в цикле

Tags: javascript

При попытке удалить все элементы из массива методом `splice` через цикл получаю следующее:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 7];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr.splice(i, 1);
  console.log(arr, i)
}

console.log(arr); // [2, 3, 0, 3, 5]
```

Код удаляет каждый второй элемент, а по задумке должен оставить пустой массив.

Ещё пример:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 7];

for (const elem of arr) {
  arr.splice(elem, 1);
  console.log(arr, elem);
}

console.log(arr); // [0, 0, 0, 3, 5, 7]
```

Здесь результат просто *странный*. Как будто метод сам решил, что удалять, а что нет.

В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Главным образом ошибка в Вашей логике. По ней Вы и в первом и во втором случае обращаетесь к массиву как будто он не изменен, но это не так Вы же удаляете элементы

В первом случае удаляя каждый раз с нарастающим индексом Вы как-бы перескакиваете через элемент, так как при удалении индексы тоже уменьшились на 1, а **i** увеличилось на 1.

```
0,1,2,3,4,5 (начальное состояние)
^
1,2,3,4,5 (при удалении элемента индексы уменьшились на 1)
^
1,2,3,4,5 (i увеличилось на 1)
  ^
```

Во втором случае Вы первым элементом передаете уже не индекс а значение элемента - тут конечно все будет не так очевидно.

Таким образом выровнять ситуацию просто:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 7];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr.splice(0, 1);
}
console.log(arr); // [0, 3, 4, 5, 7]
```

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 7];
for (const elem of arr) {
  arr.splice(0, 1);
}
console.log(arr); // [0, 3, 4, 5, 7]
```

Но это не очищает оба массива как предполагается, по причине того что массивы мутируют. А в случае `for`, `for of` и `for in` значения длины массива высчитывается не верно, заметьте, что `0, 3, 4, 5, 7` - это последние числа в массиве, до них дело просто не доходит, так как в условии `i < arr.length` и **i**, и **arr.length** движуться навстречу друг другу и останавливаются примерно на середине ,например при: **5 < 5**

Но этого не происходит при `while` который каждый раз получает актуальную длину массива и условие выхода уже соответствует ожиданиям, т.е. `while` позволяет любые мутации интегрируемого объекта, но по возможности их стоит избегать.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 7];
while (arr.length) {
  arr.splice(0, 1);
}
console.log(arr); // []
```