# Почему не удаляет первые два элемента метод forEach

Tags: javascript

```
const natural = [1, 2, 3, 4];

natural.forEach(element => natural.pop())

console.log(natural)
```

Почему не удаляет первые два элемента метод forEach? Выводит [1, 2]

Comment: я думал, что в итоге должно напечатать [ ]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Странное поведение splice в цикле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1449600/%d0%a1%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-splice-%d0%b2-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Причина в том, что при итерации методом `for`, `for in`, `for of`, `forEach` **не желательно** удалять элементы. Они "считают" что длина массива не будет меняться в процессе работы.

Кстати [тут](https://denolib.github.io/v8-docs/classv8_1_1internal_1_1ForEachStatement.html) можно увидеть что `for in` и  `for of` наследуются от `forEach`

Вот пример кода с `push` который показывает, что длина массива не отслеживается `forEach` цикл отработает только 6 раз, не бесконечно.

```js
  const natural = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  natural.forEach(element => {
    natural.push(natural.length + 1)
  })
  console.log(natural.join())
```

Почему остается половина я объяснял в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1449603/237463)

Правда в случае с `forEach` мое объяснение не очень очевидно ведь мы не задаем переменной. Происходит нечто иное. Я представил это в виде таблицы:

```
| шаг      | массив       | индекс  | значение       | действие         |
|----------|--------------|---------|----------------|------------------|
| 1        | [1, 2, 3, 4] | 0       | 1              | массив.pop()     |
| 2        | [1, 2, 3]    | 1       | 2              | массив.pop()     |
| 3        | [1, 2]       | 2       | ошибка доступа | пропуск          |
| 4        | [1]          | 3       | ошибка доступа | пропуск          |
```

Пояснения к таблице: каждая строка обозначает итерацию в цикле, и состояние массива и `element` на третьей итерации доступ получить не получится. Цикл продолжится, но его тело не вызовется, чтобы продемонстрировать это приведу еще один снипет который добавит только 3 элемента в массив `testArr` т.е.  с 4-ой итерации не будет выполнятся тело цикла:

```js
const natural = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const testArr = []
natural.forEach(element => {
  natural.pop()                // начиная с 4 итерации не выполнится
  testArr.push(element + 100)  // начиная с 4 итерации не выполнится
})
console.log(testArr)
```

**Информация из исходников v8**:
Реализация `forEach` имеет достаточно много кода, однако v8 использует [Torque](https://v8.dev/docs/torque) — язык, который позволяет разработчикам, участвующим в проекте V8, выражать изменения в виртуальной машине, сосредоточив внимание на цели своих изменений в виртуальной машине, а не занимаясь посторонними деталями реализации.

Тут приведен код в упрощенном виде:

```
function ArrayForEachLoopContinuation(context, callbackfn, thisArg, o, len)
  for (let k = 0; k < len; k = k + 1) {
    // проверяем есть ли свойство k в объекте o    
    const kPresent = HasProperty_Inline(o, k);
    // если есть то 
    if (kPresent == True) {
      // получаем значение
      const kValue = GetProperty(o, k);
      // выполняем callback тела цикла ( kValue = элемент , k = индекс, o = массив  )
      Call(context, callbackfn, thisArg, kValue, k, o);
    }
  }
  return Undefined;
}
```

Тут можно посмотреть [оригинал](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/main/src/builtins/array-foreach.tq) полностью, снипет ниже содержит приведенную выше функцию:

```js
transitioning builtin ArrayForEachLoopContinuation(implicit context: Context)(
    _receiver: JSReceiver, callbackfn: Callable, thisArg: JSAny, _array: JSAny,
    o: JSReceiver, initialK: Number, len: Number, _to: JSAny): JSAny {
  // variables {array} and {to} are ignored.

  // 5. Let k be 0.
  // 6. Repeat, while k < len
  for (let k: Number = initialK; k < len; k = k + 1) {
    // 6a. Let Pk be ! ToString(k).
    // k is guaranteed to be a positive integer, hence ToString is
    // side-effect free and HasProperty/GetProperty do the conversion inline.

    // 6b. Let kPresent be ? HasProperty(O, Pk).
    const kPresent: Boolean = HasProperty_Inline(o, k);

    // 6c. If kPresent is true, then
    if (kPresent == True) {
      // 6c. i. Let kValue be ? Get(O, Pk).
      const kValue: JSAny = GetProperty(o, k);

      // 6c. ii. Perform ? Call(callbackfn, T, <kValue, k, O>).
      Call(context, callbackfn, thisArg, kValue, k, o);
    }

    // 6d. Increase k by 1. (done by the loop).
  }
  return Undefined;
}
```

**Подробнее о коде в вопросе**:

Так как вы удаляете элементы с конца остается половина массива с начала.

```
const natural = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
natural.forEach(element => natural.pop()) // [1, 2, 3]
```

Если бы делали это же но с начала, осталась бы половина массива с конца

```
const natural = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
natural.forEach(element => natural.shift()) // [4, 5, 6]
```

Для этих целей можно использовать while ,**но это избыточно если нет других действий**

```
const natural = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
while (natural.length) natural.pop() // []
```

Это однако не значит что `for` совсем нельзя использовать для этих целей, просто нужно делать это немного по-другому (учитывая то как работает пример с while выше) задав условие выхода иначе. **Этот вариант тоже избыточен если нет других действий.**

```js
const natural = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
for (var i = 0; natural.length; i++) {
  natural.pop()
}
console.log(natural)
```

Cамым "правильным" *на мой взгляд*, будет **использование методов массива для работы с массивом**, а именно метод `splice`, который модифицирует наличие элементов массива по месту, не создавая нового массива:

```
const natural = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
natural.splice(0, natural.length); // []
```

Comment: Хм.. Что-то ты какую-то муть написал. А очищать массив вообще лучше так: `arr.length = 0`.

Comment: @Qwertiy, муть в каком месте?

Comment: Таблица вообще непонятна. А дальше сомнительные рекомендации про while и splice.

Comment: таблицу попробую прокомментировать еще,  `arr.length = 0` для меня более сомнительно (слишком уж просто, нигде не встречал рекомендации к такому написанию)

Comment: @Qwertiy, но вот в этой [статье](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/array/4-ways-empty-javascript-array/) есть и то и другое, иными словами - дело вкуса.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что `foeEach` не вызывается на дырках:

```js
[10, 20, , , 30].forEach((x, i) => console.log(x, i))
```

Берём код из вопроса:

```js
const natural = [1, 2, 3, 4];

natural.forEach(element => natural.pop())

console.log(natural)
```

и переписываем:

```js
const natural = [1, 2, 3, 4];

for (let i=0, n=natural.length; i<n; ++i) {
  if (i in natural) {
    natural.pop()
  }
}

console.log(natural)
```

Понятно, что как только `i` превысит половину размера массива, все проверки `in` станут ложными, а значит начало не удалится.